# Происходит сворачивание приложения при выполнении кода

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, мобильные-приложения

```
Пишу простейшее приложения на Андройд. Получаю весь HTML сайта и вывожу данный текст на экран смартфона. Происходить всё это в Android Studio. Создал проект с помощью шаблона "Fragment + ViewModel". В MainActiviti с помощью метода getContent подключаюсь к сайту и считываю его HTML.
Метод работает, но как только я пытаюсь сделать передачу текста на экран, приложение при запуске тут же сворачивается. Подскажите что не так. Если убрать вот эту строчку

    text_poster = findViewById(R.id.text_poster);
        try {
            text_poster.setText(getContent(URL_POSTER));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

То приложение запускается и HTML можно вывести в Log(проверял но в коде этого нет). 


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText text_poster;
    final public String URL_POSTER = "https://udmfil.ru/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, MainFragment.newInstance())
                    .commitNow();
        }
        text_poster = findViewById(R.id.text_poster);
        try {
            text_poster.setText(getContent(URL_POSTER));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public String getContent(String path) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader=null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url=new URL(path);
            connection =(HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connection.connect();
            stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuilder buf=new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buf.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            return(buf.toString());
        }
        finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
            if (stream != null) {
                stream.close();
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
}

Переделал 


    public class MainFragment extends Fragment{
    final public String URL_POSTER = "https://udmfil.ru/";


    public static MainFragment newInstance() {
        return new MainFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        DownLoad FOG = new DownLoad();
        FOG.execute(URL_POSTER);
        String result_post = String.valueOf(FOG);
        Log.i("URL",result_post);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
    }
    public class DownLoad extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String[]> {

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... strings) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader= null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    buffer.append(line);
                    Log.i("URL", String.valueOf(buffer));
                /*String pos = buffer.toString();
                int indexPost, i = 1;
                String postB;
                do {
                    indexPost = pos.indexOf("m-img buy") + 21;
                    Log.i("URL", String.valueOf(indexPost));
                    if (indexPost != -1){
                        postB = pos.substring(indexPost, indexPost + 55);
                        Log.i("URL",postB);
                        strings[i] = postB;
                        indexPost = indexPost +55;
                        pos = pos.substring(indexPost);
                        Log.i("FLAG",pos);
                        i++;
                        Log.i("FLAG",strings[i]);
                        Log.i("URL", String.valueOf(i));
                    }
                }while (indexPost != -1);*/
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null)
                    connection.disconnect();
                try {
                    if (reader != null)
                        reader.close();
                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            return strings;
        }
    }
}


java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
 at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(Unknown Source:27)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(Unknown Source:36)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(Unknown Source:23)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source:40)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(Unknown Source:2)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source:79)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source:2)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source:4)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
 at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Unknown Source:111)
 at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source:22)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source:3)
 at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:41)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:178)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:144)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:86)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:176)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:90)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
 at com.example.myapplication.ui.main.MainFragment$DownLoad.doInBackground(MainFragment.java:58)
 at com.example.myapplication.ui.main.MainFragment$DownLoad.doInBackground(MainFragment.java:48)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(Unknown Source:20)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source:31)
Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
 at libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
 at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:74)
 at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.android_getaddrinfo(BlockGuardOs.java:200)
 at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:74)
 at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Unknown Source:51)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
 
Теперь такое вот получается.
```

Comment: Пробовал делать асинхронно

через public static class DownLoad extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String[]>

Answer (score 0):

Приложение закрывается из-за того, что в коде ошибка. Где и какая именно подскажет stacktrace, его желательно скинуть сюда, ибо без этого только гадать можно, что именно не так.

upd. Эксепшн NetworkOnMainThreadException говорит о том, что вы используете сетевые запросы в главном потоке, используйте AsyncTask к примеру.

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: Сорян, не в курсе за эту тему.

Comment: В основном выходят предупреждения что AsyncTask устарел.

Comment: [deprecation] AsyncTask in android.os has been deprecated
import android.os.AsyncTask;

[deprecation] execute(Params...) in AsyncTask has been deprecated
        FOG.execute(URL_POSTER);
  where Params,Progress,Result are type-variables:
    Params extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
    Progress extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
    Result extends Object declared in class AsyncTask

[deprecation] onActivityCreated(Bundle) in Fragment has been deprecated
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

Comment: [deprecation] onActivityCreated(Bundle) in Fragment has been deprecated
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

[deprecation] AsyncTask in android.os has been deprecated
    public static class DownLoad extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String[]> {

[deprecation] doInBackground(Params...) in AsyncTask has been deprecated
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... strings) {

  where Params,Result are type-variables:
    Params extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
    Result extends Object declared in class AsyncTask

Comment: [deprecation] AsyncTask() in AsyncTask has been deprecated
    public static class DownLoad extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String[]> {

Comment: Оттого, что он устарел, работать хуже он не стал. Просто смысл в том, что работу с сетью вам не нужно обрабатывать в основном потоке, а как именно это делать - это уже на ваше усмотрение.

Answer (score 0):

Можно решить проблему так:

1. Kotlin Coroutines:

   ```
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        // вызов сетового запроса, getData должна быть suspended function
        val result = service.getData()

        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            // взаимодействие с интерфейсом, setText и т.д.
        }
    }
   ```

   Документация: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines

   Тоже неплохая статья: https://proandroiddev.com/kotlin-coroutines-in-andriod-ff0b3b399fa0
2. Если принципиально нужно написать это на Java, тогда можно воспользоваться RxJava

   https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/RxJava/article.html